# Android: How to remove title padding when using sliding tabs toolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I am following [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html) tutorial. The tutorial basically helps to create a sliding tab menu by using the AppCompat library. It basically creates a custom toolbar using the tabs and then replaces the standard ActionBar with this toolbar.

It works perfectly, but I do not wish to show the title. I only want the tabs at the top of the screen to be my main navigation. On my activity I have set

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
```

but this only makes the text for the title blank. Space (padding?) is still reserved for the title. How do I remove it?

The picture below shows the problem visually.

[image]

Comment: Try this  getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: So simple. Thanks, it works.